# How to set a variable to read multiple columns from an excel file using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to set a variable to read multiple columns from an excel file using pandas but it keeps giving me errors, what am I doing wrong?

I have tried this:

```
import pandas

dataset = pandas.read_excel('dataset.xlsx')

features = ["B", "D", "E"]

x = dataset(columns=[features])
```

But this gave me an error saying:

```
 line 7, in <module>
    x = dataset(columns=[features])
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

I also tried this:

```
import pandas

dataset = pandas.read_excel('dataset.xlsx')

features = ["B", "D", "E"]

x = dataset[[features]]
```

Which gave this error " raise:

```
 KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: None of [Index([('B', 'D', 'E')], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You pass a list of lists (with length 1) instead of a list. Remove the additional `[]` around `features`:

```
x = dataset[features]
```

Comment: ah ok thanks, the first one still gives an error but the second one works. Thank you

Comment: You're right, that code didn't make sense. I've removed it and only kept the working line. Thanks!